# Modify jQuery tab plugin to display specific tab on load [includes JSFiddle]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jack Moore's jQuery tabs demo (http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/). I need to modify the JS to display a specific tab initially (I thought about modifying the URL but that won't work in the scenario I need this for).

I've got everything set up in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sfSex/

```
 $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
      // Make the old tab inactive.
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $content.hide();

      // Update the variables with the new link and content
      $active = $(this);
      $content = $(this.hash);

      // Make the tab active.
      $active.addClass('active');
      $content.show();

      // Prevent the anchor's default click action
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

I'm confident it's a very straightforward fix but I haven't been able to find an answer online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/J4N7Y/)

```
$(".tabs li:eq( 2 ) a").trigger("click");
```

I have triggered the Tab 3 from the list of tabs automatically on page load after few miliseconds.

I hope this solves your issue...!!

Regards D.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the following comment in code

> // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
>   `$active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);`

So if you want to select a particular tab by default; instead of the above, simply

specify tab you want to display as active like

```
$active = $links[3]; or $active = $('selector);
```